# losing dataframe when using do.call

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to merge a number of dataframes using rbind. If I call rbind directy there is no problem:

```
> test <- rbind(x)
> is.data.frame(x)
[1] TRUE
```

however, if I use `do.call` I run into a problem where my character columns are collapsed and the dataframe is converted to a matrix.

```
>test <- do.call("rbind", x)
> is.data.frame(test)
[1] FALSE
```

As per the ?rbind documentation i tried `add stringsAsFactors = FALSE` but no change in behavior.  My data tables look something like this:

```
ID  sequence    descriptor
1   aaacccttt   g12
2   actttgtgt   e34
3   tttgggctc   b12
4   ccgcgcgcg   c12
…   …       ...
```

and the rbind output looks like this but the `do.call("rbind", x)` output appears as follows, where the sequence column is no longer a character:

```
ID  363 426 91
Sequence 98 353 100
descriptor  g12 b12 c12
```

I would like to use do.call because I am looping through a set of dataframes in order to consolidate them using a script below. Another helpful answer might offer an alternative solution on how to merge multiple dataframes while calling them in a loop.

```
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
dfs <- as.list(ls(pattern="Data_"))
for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
  x <- get(as.character(dfs[i]))
  AllData <- do.call("rbind", x) 
  }
```

`dfs` is the list of dataframes in my working environment and I get the actual dataframe using `get`

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different issues causing you difficulties.

- `stringsAsFactors`

You're right to be looking at `stringsAsFactors`, but just haven't called it in quite the right place.

You have two options. You can either set it in your `options`, like this:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Or in the code used to create your `data.table`s:

```
a <- read.table(textConnection("ID  sequence    descriptor
1   aaacccttt   g12
2   actttgtgt   e34
3   tttgggctc   b12
4   ccgcgcgcg   c12"),
header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

- `args=` argument to `do.call()`

You're also on the right track in wanting to use `do.call()` for this. But, as @Sacha points out, `dfs` needs to be a list of `data.frame`s, not a single `data.frame` (which is itself a list of vectors).

```
# Create list of two data.frames
b <- a
dfs <- list(a, b)

# Or, if you start with a list of their names
dfs <- list("a", "b")
dfs <- lapply(dfs, get)

# Check that this works
do.call("rbind", dfs)
#   ID  sequence descriptor
# 1  1 aaacccttt        g12
# 2  2 actttgtgt        e34
# 3  3 tttgggctc        b12
# 4  4 ccgcgcgcg        c12
# 5  1 aaacccttt        g12
# 6  2 actttgtgt        e34
# 7  3 tttgggctc        b12
# 8  4 ccgcgcgcg        c12
```

This should also work for you even if you have just a single `data.frame`, as long as it is wrapped in a (length-1) `list`, like this: `dfs <- list(a)`

Answer (score 2):

Using Josh' example code. I am pretty sure that what is happening is this:

```
Data:
    x <- read.table(textConnection("ID  sequence    descriptor
    1   aaacccttt   g12
    2   actttgtgt   e34
    3   tttgggctc   b12
    4   ccgcgcgcg   c12"),
    header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

First this:

```
rbind(x)
```

does nothing since there is only one argument. I.e. there is nothing to append to the data frame so it just returns the same dataframe. Then:

```
do.call("rbind", x)
```

What happens here is that `rbind()` is called with all the arguments in the list `x`. A data frame is a list with columns as elements. Therefore, this would be the same as:

```
rbind(x$ID,x$sequence,x$descriptor)
```

so you put three vectors together by row. Hence, this becomes the transpose of what you had and since data.frames only store different types of vectors columnwise this must become a character matrix.

I think that if `x` is a list of dataframes it works fine. It just shouldn't be a data frame itself.

Comment: thank you Sacha, i think you've perfectly described whats happening

Answer (score 1):

I think what you seek can be done without a loop using `Reduce`. It is a higher order function, which successively applies a function to two elements from a list.

```
dfs <- as.list(ls(pattern="Data_"))
Reduce('rbind', dfs)
```

Comment: thank you Ramnath, however when I try this approach I do not return a dataset but rather a character matrix. I did not know about Reduce so I will definitely look into it.